# Group keys into same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm struggling with some chart data problems.

I have an array like this

```
 [
    {date: '17:18:21', throughput_series: '149.28'},
    {date: '17:18:31', throughput_series: '168.25'},
    {date: '17:18:21', avg_response_time_series: '111.04'},
    {date: '17:18:31', avg_response_time_series: '155.39'},
    {date: '17:18:21', max_active_user_series: '297.42'}
    {date: '17:18:31', max_active_user_series: '174.41'}    
]
```

But I want to like this

```
  [
        {date: '17:18:21', throughput_series: '149.28', avg_response_time_series: '111.04', max_active_user_series: '297.42'},
        {date: '17:18:31', throughput_series: '168.25', avg_response_time_series: '155.39', max_active_user_series: '174.41'},
  ]
```

How can I extract into the same object with a given date?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: No, I have different keys.

Comment: Why did you close the issue? That answer not working for me...

Comment: The duplicate question's top answer is key-agnostic.

Comment: You can try via console.